# How to get my grub2 Ubuntu  Win10 Bootloader (back)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I prepared (gParted) my multi-boot system (using gpt partition table, as my BIOS is UEFI-Mode enabled...)

```
/dev/sda1  ntfs  "Win"      50 GB
/dev/sda2  ext4  "Boot"     1 GB   → for "/boot"
/dev/sda3  ext4  "Linux"    89 GB  → for _crypt Volume, therein "/"
/dev/sda4  fat   "Xfer"     ca 27 GB  (the rest) transfer partition (one day…)
```

Then installed Windows 10 Pro (which btw. cut that first partition into 4 during install, [which is normal behaviour](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/40rhnd/why_does_the_windows_installer_make_4_partitions/). But all the same, install worked nicely, I could repeatedly boot Win10, change stuff, etc..).

Then I went for the Ubuntu-Mate 16.0.4 LTS install, went for the extend "something else" option. Although a ready first option for windows multi-boot was on offer, but I wanted encryption, so I made the 89GB partion "pyhsical volume for encryption" and then within "/". (I have done this ubuntu installing part many times. Should not be the problem…)

**Anyway, after seemingly sucessfull install and first reboot I am now staring at a minimal grub prompt:**

[image]

**Now what? How to get my/any bootloader (back)?**

And/or how to diagnose problems?

Comment: From live installer post: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: When my boot goes awry the first thing I do is boot with Live-USB and run boot-repair. Two or three times now it brought grub back.

Answer (score 1):

This is what will get you going (in case you don't have a handy Live-USB). Once in grub prompt :

#### List partitions

`grub> ls`

> (hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)

#### Identify Linux partition

If you don't know which is the Linux bootable partition try

`grub> ls (hd0,1)/`  *<sup>the ending slash means root ~ lists the root of partition 1</sup>*

On my system it was *(hd0,msdos5)* so the command would be :

`grub> ls (hd0,5)/`

The output should be similar to :

> lost+found/ bin/ boot/ cdrom/ dev/ etc/ home/  lib/
>   lib64/ media/ mnt/ opt/ proc/ root/ run/ sbin/
>   srv/ sys/ tmp/ usr/ var/ vmlinuz vmlinuz.old
>   initrd.img initrd.img.old

#### Boot into Linux

Using <kbd>tab</kbd> key will auto-complete kernel names in the commands bellow

`grub> set root=(hd0,5)`
`grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-39-generic root=/dev/sda5`  *
`grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-39-generic`
`grub> boot`

*<sup>* sda1 corresponds to (hd0,1) - mind that in GRUB partitions and devices were indexed startinf with 0 whereas in GRUB 2 partition indexing starts with 1</sup>*

Locations of kernel files are probably sym-linked so this gets simple

`grub> set root=(hd0,1)`
`grub> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1`
`grub> initrd /initrd.img`
`grub> boot`

That should boot into Linux, no questions asked.

#### Fix GRUB

`$ sudo update-grub`

At this point the boot should be recovered no matter the number of present operating systems. Including windows.

---

The honor for those instructions goes to [Carla's How to Rescue a Non-booting GRUB 2 on Linux](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux) post. I recommend reading it as it includes many details and know-how.

I dare say that my system's boot got corrupt by Win10 update. However, one should never say that Windows or Bill shouldn't exist. They were a historical driving force which created the right circumstances for such a great OS as Linux.

Comment: Sorry, took me so long to get back to my setup. ls(hd0,5)/ has some stuff like `lost+found/` `efi/` `grub/ vmlinuz... but no `boot/`. My boot partition should be (see above) (hd0,2) and indeed has efi/ folder and inside is an `bootx64.efi`... any suggestion what to do with that?